# Enable a backdoor in WebMatrix accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webmatrix

In a web server built with ASP.NET/MVC, I am using WebMatrix to manage the users.
I would like to create some kind of backdoor to enter in any customer account, so it would help me with the technical support to see exactly what they are seeing.

I have thought to create an "universal" password, so I could enter to any account just knowing the user name.

In the controller, I can see:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
{
     return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

How could I do it? In any case, it seems a fragile system. Which alternatives are webs using?

Thanks

Comment: This would defeat the entire purpose of users having passwords, since you-in creating this backdoor- enables anyone access that can get ahold of the backdoor password. If I understand you right.

Comment: You may write your own MembershipProvider(Ex) (where if universal password is provided you'll always validate it). You just need to override few methods. In alternative you may setup an administration account where you see their password (if you don't store them hashed).

Comment: @MarcusWigert not sure what you mean. He's not going to publish the password. Anyone can get into any account if he has the password.

Comment: using a master password in the way you described it would undermine the whole concept of authentication
you should rather implement an `admin role` within your application that can be assinged to a user or group

Comment: @usr - If a standard password is lost => 1 account compromised. If the master password is lost => every single account is compromised. That's a big flaw. A master password is **not** a good idea.

Comment: @RobH I understand that but it's not *his* point. It's a different concern.

Comment: The master password only would be in my possession, in central office. I am clear that if this password is lost, then anybody can access to all accounts just knowing the usernames, but it is exactly the same problem that if I lose my admin password. If somebody has my admin password, can reset any user password or do anything, so, in the end, they could access to any account too.

Comment: you should also be aware that you will not be able to destinguish between changes that have been made by a "real" user or someone using the users account via the master password

Comment: @DabielKabuto One big difference (in addition to what user1859022 said) is that you can reset an admin password without having to recompile and redeploy your application! Seriously - just use a roles provider. You'll almost certainly want support for roles at some point anyway, so you might as well bake it in now...